# Polymer 1.0 dom-repeat with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, polymer-1.0

I am using the latest App Toolbox and app shell structure for my polymer 1.0 project and I am having issues with a `dom-repeat` template in a custom element, the `google-map-markers` are not showing up inside the `dom-repeat` template.

Here is the code:

```
<dom-module ="sample-map">
   <style>
       :host {
           display: block;
           padding: 10px;
       }

       #mapWrapper{
           height: 600px;
           display:block;
           width: auto;
       }
   </style>
   <template>
      <google-map api-key="MY_API_KEY" fit-to-markers>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{locations}}">
              <google-map-marker latitude="{{item.latitude}}" longitude="{{item.longitude}}"></google-map-marker>
          </template>   
      </google-map>
   </template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'sample-map',
        properties:{
            locations:{
                type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: function(){
                    return [];
                }
            }
        },
        addLocation: function(location){
            this.push('locations', location);
        },
        getLocations: function(){
            //.. performs request to get locations from a server
            MyLibrary.get('http://api.testurl.com/locations', function(response){
                  for(var item in response){
                     var location = response[item];
                     this.addLocation(location);
                  }
            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

This is pretty much it. I have verified the locations Array is being added to, but after the locations are populated there is no drawing of the `google-map-marker`s.

If i statically set the array, the `google-map-marker`s show up. I have done this exact same thing before without the App shell structure and it works, however before I was not binding the function using `.bind(this)`.

1) Does the `.bind(this)` limit my scope for the Array and not actually update the locations Array property?

2) How do I update the `google-map` after my array changes using the array mutations in polymer?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation lists a private `_updateMarkers` method in `google-map` element. Does it do the trick? Calling private API is hacky. Unless someone answers here maybe you should raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map)

Comment: In fact there exists such an issue already: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/149

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz i saw this issue, was unsure if this was already fixed in next update of GoogleWebComponents/google-map. Anyways looks like i will have to wait, i don't want to try to call private API methods or at least use this in the interim. Also i have confirmed my  .bind(this) is working on the element's scope, so it does update the locations array and the template does repeat google-map-marker, they just don't display

Comment: I would reopen that issue if I were you